# How can I force the page thumbnail Menu in an <embed> html tag to default to closed?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I am using an HTML embed tag to display a PDF in a webpage similarly to this:

Code:

```
<div>
    <embed src={sourceURL} type="application/pdf" />
</div>
```

As expected, the viewer gives me a menu button which allows me to expand and collapse this page view.

[Menu Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgF1S.png)

[Menu Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt77z.png)

However, in some browsers like Chrome, the viewer retains the previous open or closed state of the menu when you refresh or revisit the page, and in other browsers the menu always defaults to the open state even if previously left closed.

Is there a way to control the embed tag that will default the menu's state to close?

As mentioned, the embed pdf viewer saves open and closed states for the menu in Chrome, but if trying to integrate into something like a #C browser, the menu does not save the previous open or closed state.  Researching the  tag, it doesn't appear this has an out of the box property I can attach to keep it always closed.

Comment: `Is there a way to control the embed tag that will default the menu's state to close?` No. The PDF viewer is part of the browser and not configurable by JS